# Python:Initialize a list in a class constructor

Tags: python

I am trying to initialize a list in a class like this:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self):
        self.info = None
        self.word = ''
        for i in range(256):
            self.ptrs[0] = None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = Node()
```

Now this throws an error

```
self.ptrs[0] = None
AttributeError: Node instance has no attribute 'ptrs'
```

I am sure that I'm missing something stupid. What is it?

Answer (score 3):

I think you want this:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self):
        self.info = None
        self.word = ''
        self.ptrs = [None]*256
```